# Unique identifier for chemical substances?

Tags: databases

One famous database for chemical substances is [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/). If one reads the [section about other identifiers than the PubChem ID for Ethanol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/702#section=Other-Identifiers) one gets several CAS numbers (potentially deprecated ones as well), potentially several European Community (EC) Numbers and a lot of other identifiers which seem to be not really unique.

Is there a true unique identifier for chemical substances reasonable to be used in a database?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/pubchem-inchi-smiles-and-uniqueness is relevant, although not a direct answer. The short answer is : Yes, InChI but there are alternatives

Comment: This one is more relevant : https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110057/how-to-index-molecules-in-computer-programs

Comment: The point of CAS numbers is that they label mixtures and preparations, not just pure chemicals. If you want a 1:1 mapping from a chemical to a database identifier, CAS numbers aren't even the right tool to look at in your case.

Comment: @gilleain Seems like there is ununiqueness cause of "standard" and "non-standard" InChi as well with InChi.

Comment: In additon, _polymorphs_ of the same compound may be filed under different CAS register numbers, too.  Example:  $\ce{TiO2}$, as anatase (1317-70-0), and as rutil (131-80-2) -- both tetragonal, but either $I4_1/amd$, packing fraction 70%; or $P4_2/mnm$, packing fraction 77%.  Source: Cardelli, Materials Handbook, 3rd edition 2018, Springer Cham/Switzerland, ISBN 978-3-319-39823-3, p. 910, table 10.8.  And since polymorphs may differ, e.g. in dissolution kinetics, this is relevant for pharmaceutical materials, too.